# What are the postgis-3 other postgis_*-3 extensions?

Tags: postgis, extensions

The [PostGIS Installation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/postgis_installation.html) instructions show using `CREATE EXTENSION` to create PostGIS and several related extensions (see below).

After recently installing PostgreSQL 14.6 on Ubuntu,¹ I went to create these extensions. When I look at the available extensions, all of the extensions listed below except for `fyzzystrmatch` appear as shown *and* as `postgis-3`, `postgis_raster-3`, etc. The available version numbers are the same for all of them, leading me to believe that they are just aliases, but I can't find any information about them in the documentation.

What are the `postgis_*-3` extensions? Is there any difference between them and the "base" extensions, and is there a reason to prefer either one?

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch; --needed for postgis_tiger_geocoder
--optional used by postgis_tiger_geocoder, or can be used standalone
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer;
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

---

¹ Actually done by a colleague.

Comment: This seems like more an IT/config release issue with Ubuntu than a GIS-centric problem.

Comment: Have you read the documentation, for example https://postgis.net/docs/standardize_address.html, https://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html, https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal

Comment: As the question states, I can't find any information about this in the documentation. If I've missed something and you can find a place in the documentation that specifically addresses the question, please let me know.

Comment: How did you get a list of extensions? Anyway, what you see comes from the way how extensions are handled in PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html. However, the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-available-extension-versions.html function gives me a list with exact version numbers: `"(postgis,3.1.2,t,f,,,"PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions")"`

Comment: The `*-3` lines that you see are probably referring to the module names in the filesystem. For example, my postgis_raster.control file has an entry `module_pathname = '$libdir/postgis_raster-3'`, and in that directory I have a binary file `postgis_raster-3.dll`. I do not know why your Ubuntu system is listing those *-3 things. Do you have also corresponding .control files, for example `postgis_raster-3.control`? In any case, there is no GIS component in this question really.

Comment: `SELECT pg_available_extensions();` which returns `(postgis,3.2.0,"PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions")` *and* `(postgis-3,3.2.0,"PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions")`.

Comment: Regarding whether the question is on topic, this SE has often answered questions with tags [postgis] and [installation]. It is likely to be generated by someone like me who is primarily a GISP and not a Postgres DBA or Ubuntu sysadmin, and I think the knowledge to answer it is more likely to be found in this community as well. Also, I see nothing similar in other non-PostGIS extensions (i.e., extensions with possibly duplicated names with what might be a version number appended). I would appreciate if this be taken into consideration in a possible vote to close.